# "Only by playing fair, and also without fear, will you ever win."

Tags: meaning

"Only by playing fair, and also without fear, will you ever win."

What is its meaning?

I don't understand the last part "will you ever win". Is it a question?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As Stack Exchange seeks to build a library of definitive questions and answers, your question should describe in detail what it is you do not understand and what attempts you have made to parse it through your own research. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: I think this ELL answer definitely helps. https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/80071/29183